# How can I align a list item imbedded in another list?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a dropdown menu at the top of my page; however, I am unable to properly align the edges of the two list item elements.

Picture of the problem:
[image: Picture of the problem]

### This is my code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Chivo Mono";
  src: url("Resource/Fonts/ChivoMono-Black.ttf") format("ttf");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
  color: #777;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.emails {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header {
  background-color: #A7C7E7;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 150, 190, 1);
}

.main-nav {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(255, 150, 190, 1);
}

.main-nav li {
  padding: 0 5%;
}

.page-name {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: "Chivo Mono";
  font-weight: normal;
  color: rgba(255, 150, 150, 1);
}

.footer {
  background-color: #A7C7E7;
  margin: 50px 0px;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  border: white;
}

.footer h1 {
  padding: 0px 0px;
}

.footer textarea {
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.body-text {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.email-button {
  padding: 1em;
}

.article-title h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: Black;
}

.coming-soon {
  color: white;
}

.nav li {
  color: white;
}

.email-button button {
  background-color: rgba(255, 150, 190, 1);
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  transition-duration: 0.9s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #A7C7E7;
}

.dropdown ul li a {
  font-size: .6em;
}

.dropdown ul a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(255, 150, 190, 1);
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <nav class="nav main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a>Rules</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="gunlawramble.html">Bus</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <h1 class="page-name">About</h1>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="body-text">
  <div>
    <p text>To be writen...
      <p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have tried messing with the paddings and margins, as well as display types.

Comment: Can you include an image or explanation of what you want this to look like? It's not clear which sides need to be aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust it with `position` as below:

```css
nav .dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
nav .dropdown ul {
  position: absolute;
}
nav > ul .dropdown > ul,
nav > ul .dropdown > ul li {
  padding-left:0;
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) is the doc for `position` if you want to know more.

### DEMO

```css
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Chivo Mono";
  src: url("Resource/Fonts/ChivoMono-Black.ttf") format("ttf");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
} 

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
  color: #777;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

p {
  text-align:center;
}

.emails {
  height:100px;
  width:250px;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header {
  background-color:#A7C7E7;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:1em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 150, 190, 1);
}

.main-nav {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(255, 150, 190, 1);
}

.main-nav li {
  padding: 0 5%;
}

.page-name {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: "Chivo Mono";
  font-weight: normal;
  color: rgba(255, 150, 150, 1);
}

.footer {
  background-color: #A7C7E7;
  margin: 50px 0px;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  border: white;
}
.footer h1  {
    padding: 0px 0px;
}

.footer textarea {
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.body-text {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.email-button {
  padding: 1em;
}

.article-title h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: Black;
}

.coming-soon {
  color: white;
}

.nav li {
  color: white;
}

.email-button button {
  background-color: rgba(255, 150, 190, 1);
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  transition-duration: 0.9s;  
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #A7C7E7;
}

.dropdown ul li a {
  font-size: .6em;

}

.dropdown ul a{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(255, 150, 190, 1);
  text-align: center;
}
nav .dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
nav > ul .dropdown > ul {
  position: absolute;
}
nav > ul .dropdown > ul,
nav > ul .dropdown > ul li{
  padding-left:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="zuckymuckyboi" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources\styles.css">
    <style></style>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <nav class="nav main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href= "index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a>Rules</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href= "gunlawramble.html">Bus</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <h1 class="page-name">About</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="body-text">
        <div>
            <p text>To be writen...<p>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: This doesn’t really solve my problem. I want the two edges of the backgrounds to long up on the left side. Currently the left side of rules element is to the left of the edge of the bus list item element.

Comment: @JFP you just need to remove the padding on your `ul` and `li`. You did not precise which align was wrong so hard to guess

Answer (score -1):

This is really just a hack to get what you are trying to do:

```
<li style="padding-right:119px;"><a href= "gunlawramble.html">Bus</a></li>
```

Using inline css styling you can add a padding to the specific element you want to adjust.

In this case, you can see `padding-right:119px` aligns the elements to the left side.

If you want the elements to align on the opposite side, you can similarly use `padding-left` and adjust in the same manner.

```css
@font-face { 
    font-family: "Chivo Mono";
    src: url("Resource/Fonts/ChivoMono-Black.ttf") format("ttf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
} 

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
    color: #777;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}


.emails {
    height:100px; width:250px;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.header {
    background-color:#A7C7E7;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px
}

.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:1em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

.nav a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 150, 190, 1);
}

.main-nav {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(255, 150, 190, 1)
}

.main-nav li {
    padding: 0 5%;
}

.page-name {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-family: "Chivo Mono";
    font-weight: normal;
    color: rgba(255, 150, 150, 1);
}

.footer {
    background-color: #A7C7E7;
    margin: 50px 0px;
    padding: 50px 0px;
    border: white;
}
.footer h1  {
    padding: 0px 0px
}

.footer textarea {
    margin-top: 2em;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

.body-text {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.5em
}

.footer {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10em;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.email-button {
    padding: 1em;
}

.article-title h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: Black;
}

.coming-soon {
    color: white;
}

.nav li {
    color: white;
}

.email-button button {
    background-color: rgba(255, 150, 190, 1);
    color: white;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 0px;
    transition-duration: 0.9s;  
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #A7C7E7;
}

.dropdown ul li a {
    font-size: .6em;
}

.dropdown ul a{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(255, 150, 190, 1);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="zuckymuckyboi" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources\styles.css">
    <style>
        p {
            text-align:center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <nav class="nav main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href= "index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a>Rules</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li style="padding-right:119px;"><a href= "gunlawramble.html">Bus</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <h1 class="page-name">About</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="body-text">
        <div>
            <p text>To be writen...<p>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you just check and guess the number of pixels to move it to the right spot?

Comment: @JFP Yes that is why I called it a hack. There are preferred ways to doing this but if you just want it to look right it is very easy to adjust on the pixel level using padding

Comment: What is the preferred way to do this? Your "hack" worked I would just like to know the proper way to do this for the future. Thank you.

Comment: @JFP Using flexbox is a good option, if you get too used to manually assigning pixel transformations it gets very time consuming and doesn't propagate well across different screen sizes